# Python Updating a regex dictionary using the previous expression/key?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have this function that replaces a named rule in the value of a dictionary, like #digit#, with its regular expression counterpart: [0-9)

So for example, calling this function:

```
def expand_re(pat_dict:{str:str}):
    pat_list = list(pat_dict.items())
    for key, rule in pat_dict.items():
        expression = re.compile(r'#\w+#')
        pat_dict[key] = re.sub(expression, f"(?:{pat_list[0][1]})", rule)
    return pat_dict
```

on this dictionary:
`pd = dict(digit = r'[0-9]', integer = r'[+-]?#digit##digit#*')`
Would produce:
`{'digit': '[0-9]', 'integer': '[+-]?(?:[0-9])(?:[0-9])*'}`

And it works just fine for that. However, if a dictionary starts using the previous value's named rule, it does not work. So calling expand_re on the dictionary:

`pd = dict(a='correct',b='#a#',c='#b#',d='#c#',e='#d#',f='#e#',g='#f#')`

My function produces:

```
{'a': 'correct',
 'b': '(?:correct)',
 'c': '(?:correct)',
 'd': '(?:correct)',
 'e': '(?:correct)',
 'f': '(?:correct)',
 'g': '(?:correct)'
}
```

When I want it to produce:

```
{'a': 'correct',
 'b': '(?:correct)',
 'c': '(?:(?:correct))',
 'd': '(?:(?:(?:correct)))',
 'e': '(?:(?:(?:(?:correct))))',
 'f': '(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:correct)))))',
 'g': '(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:correct))))))'
}
```

How would I be able to do this? I've tried using the dictionary's .update() method, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix of your code which works as you want. Be aware though that the logic is the same and it has the flaw that the keys are replaced **in order**. This means it won't do what you want if the keys are shuffled.

```
import re
def expand_re(pat_dict:{str:str}): 
    expression = re.compile(r'#(\w+)#')
    for key in pat_dict:
        pat_dict[key] = re.sub(expression, lambda x: f"(?:{pat_dict[x.group(1)]})", pat_dict[key])
    return pat_dict

d = dict(a='correct',b='#a#',c='#b#',d='#c#',e='#d#',f='#e#',g='#f#')

expand_re(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'correct',
 'b': '(?:correct)',
 'c': '(?:(?:correct))',
 'd': '(?:(?:(?:correct)))',
 'e': '(?:(?:(?:(?:correct))))',
 'f': '(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:correct)))))',
 'g': '(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:correct))))))'}
```

##### example demonstrating the (potential) flaw in the logic

```
>>> expand_re(dict(a='correct',b='#a#',c='#b#',e='#d#',d='#c#',f='#e#',g='#f#'))
{'a': 'correct',
 'b': '(?:correct)',
 'c': '(?:(?:correct))',
 'e': '(?:#c#)',
 'd': '(?:(?:(?:correct)))',
 'f': '(?:(?:#c#))',
 'g': '(?:(?:(?:#c#)))'}
```

##### version without regex

```
def expand_re(pat_dict:{str:str}): 
    for key, value in pat_dict.items():
        if value.startswith('#') and value.endswith('#') and value[1:-1] in pat_dict:
            pat_dict[key] = f'(?:{pat_dict[value[1:-1]]}'
    return pat_dict
```

Comment: Also if what you want to do is not more complicated than the substitution described here you do not need a regex (nor a lambda). You just need to concatenate `'(?:'` and `')'` to the matching key

Comment: Noted. That is indeed a lot simpler. I was attempting to practice utilizing re methods, but perhaps this is overcomplicating the task.